# Wordpress - Undefined index on unset field

Tags: wordpress, undefined-index

Still trying to figure my way around Wordpress plugin development, how can I resolve this undefined error? This appears when I add a new post, it can't find the post so I'm trying to figure out how to resolve it with an isset.

`Notice: Undefined index: kk_youtube in /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/video_widget/video_widget.php on line 33`

The error is on this line 33:

```
$youtube_link = esc_attr($value['kk_youtube'][0]);
```

I've been trying to wrap it in `isset($post)` but it's still not working.

This is the entire function call.

```
function kk_youtube_handler($post) {
    $value = get_post_custom($post->ID);

    $youtube_link = esc_attr($value['kk_youtube'][0]);

    echo '<label for="kk_youtube">YouTube Video Link</label>
          <input type="text" id="kk_youtube" name="kk_youtube" value="' . 
          $youtube_link . '" />';
}
```

Can I get some help on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your form is no name="kk_youtube[]" or name="kk_youtube[0]" attribute.

Use

```
$value['kk_youtube']
```

instead of

```
$value['kk_youtube'][0]
```

**EDIT:**

```
$youtube_link = isset($value['kk_youtube']) ? esc_attr($value['kk_youtube']) : '';
```

Comment: Do you mean for this line? `$youtube_link = esc_attr($value['kk_youtube'][0]);` to use `$value['kk_youtube']` ? If so, I still the undefined error.

Comment: @esteemed.squire: impossible, check for typos. It has to work.

Comment: @esteemed.squire: You can add condition if the value really exists, see the update.